# Get all Extensions of the ExtensionFilters of a FileChooser

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, filechooser

I want to add an `ExtensionFilter` (supported Files) in the end with all the extensions of the previous filters to a `FileChooser`.

This is what I've tried:

```
FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();

chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
        new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg"),
        new ExtensionFilter("Video Files", "*.mp4")), //And so on...

ArrayList<String> supportedExt = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int x = 0; x < chooser.getExtensionFilters().size(); x++) {

    // And here I get this:
    //The method addAll(Collection<? extends String>) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (FileChooser.ExtensionFilter)
    supportedExt.addAll(chooser.getExtensionFilters().get(x)); 
}

chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("supported Files", supportedExt));
```

As you can see, I get this error:

> The method addAll(Collection) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (FileChooser.ExtensionFilter)

Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you all you need to know. `chooser.getExtensionFilters()` returns list of `FileChooser.ExtensionFilter` but your `supportedExt` is defined to accept `String`.

You probably intended:

`supportedExt.addAll( chooser.getExtensionFilters().get(x).getExtensions() );`

Answer (score 0):

It's b/c you declared `supportedExt` as `List<String>`.
You should use `getExtensions()` in class `FileChooser.ExtensionFilter`